# how to prefix a text with grep output

Tags: windows, grep

I want to read the logs logged between time 7:00:59 and 08:00:59 from  ABCD_ERR.LOG and search some strings in those set of log lines and store the searched output lines to output.txt. But I want to prepend inputfilename ie.ABCD_ERR.LOG also with the outputlines.
For example,
ABCD_ERR.LOG contains logs like

```
        Server 07972 006856 06:06:14.203 CleanUp - Elapsed 16 usec - Info : Session does not contain modified objects in cache.
Communications 06480 006584 07:01:56.140 Elapsed 94592 usec - Container Temperature (80)
        Server 07972 006860 07:06:20.281 Elapsed 516245941539 usec - No of resources in array = 0
Communications 06480 006584 07:11:56.140 Elapsed 92355 usec - Container Temperature (80)
        Server 07972 006860 07:16:21.296 Elapsed 516846919543 usec - No of resources in array = 0
Communications 06480 006584 07:21:56.140 Elapsed 89978 usec - Container Temperature (80)
        Server 07972 006860 07:26:22.296 CleanUpThread - Elapsed 517447899556 usec  
            BE 05452 009252 08:37:25.375 Elapsed 87 usec - Updating SESSION_ID
        Server 04616 004744 09:24:12.437 Initialize() - Elapsed 7132 usec
```

Regfile.txt contains

```
Container Temperature
Updating SESSION_ID
```

And the following is what I am doing:

```
grep -E "(07:[0-9][0-9]:|08:[0-9][0-9]:).*" ABCD_ERR.LOG|grep -E -f Regfile.txt > output.txt
```

But I want the output (prefixing filename with outputline) as

```
ABCD_ERR.LOG:Communications 06480 006584 07:01:56.140 Elapsed 94592 usec - Container Temperature (80)
ABCD_ERR.LOG:Communications 06480 006584 07:11:56.140 Elapsed 92355 usec - Container Temperature (80)
ABCD_ERR.LOG:Communications 06480 006584 07:21:56.140 Elapsed 89978 usec - Container Temperature (80)
ABCD_ERR.LOG:       BE 05452 009252 08:37:25.375 Elapsed 87 usec - Updating SESSION_ID
```

Is there any way to get the desired output as shown above?
I have tried /dev/null option, but giving error as"grep: write error on standard output: The pipe is being closed." since input to the second grep is not a file.
I am using grep in windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got solution for my question
This is what I used:

```
grep -E "(07:[0-5][0-9]:|08:[0-5][0-9]:).*" ABCD_ERR.LOG | grep --label=ABCD_ERR.LOG -H -E -f Regfile.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for awk, not grep. This will do what you say you you're having trouble with (prepending the file name):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{re=(re?re"|":"")$0; next} /07:[0-9][0-9]:|08:[0-9][0-9]:/ && ($0 ~ re){print FILENAME":"$0}' Regfile.txt ABCD_ERR.LOG
ABCD_ERR.LOG:Communications 06480 006584 07:01:56.140 Elapsed 94592 usec - Container Temperature (80)
ABCD_ERR.LOG:Communications 06480 006584 07:11:56.140 Elapsed 92355 usec - Container Temperature (80)
ABCD_ERR.LOG:Communications 06480 006584 07:21:56.140 Elapsed 89978 usec - Container Temperature (80)
ABCD_ERR.LOG:            BE 05452 009252 08:37:25.375 Elapsed 87 usec - Updating SESSION_ID
```

but note that your regexp for identifying the times within your target range is wrong. Here's one way you can really check for a given time being within a given range that same day:

```
$ cat tst.awk
(t2s($4) >= t2s("7:00:59")) && (t2s($4) <= t2s("8:00:59"))

function t2s(time,      a) {
    split(time,a,/:/)
    return (((a[1] * 60) + a[2]) * 60) + a[3]
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Communications 06480 006584 07:01:56.140 Elapsed 94592 usec - Container Temperature (80)
        Server 07972 006860 07:06:20.281 Elapsed 516245941539 usec - No of resources in array = 0
Communications 06480 006584 07:11:56.140 Elapsed 92355 usec - Container Temperature (80)
        Server 07972 006860 07:16:21.296 Elapsed 516846919543 usec - No of resources in array = 0
Communications 06480 006584 07:21:56.140 Elapsed 89978 usec - Container Temperature (80)
        Server 07972 006860 07:26:22.296 CleanUpThread - Elapsed 517447899556 usec
```

so then you can combine both scripts to do what I think you really want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { re=(re?re"|":"")$0; next }

($0 ~ re) && (t2s($4) >= t2s("7:00:59")) && (t2s($4) <= t2s("8:00:59")) { print FILENAME ":" $0 }

function t2s(time,      a) {
    split(time,a,/:/)
    return (((a[1] * 60) + a[2]) * 60) + a[3]
}

$ awk -f tst.awk Regfile.txt ABCD_ERR.LOG
ABCD_ERR.LOG:Communications 06480 006584 07:01:56.140 Elapsed 94592 usec - Container Temperature (80)
ABCD_ERR.LOG:Communications 06480 006584 07:11:56.140 Elapsed 92355 usec - Container Temperature (80)
ABCD_ERR.LOG:Communications 06480 006584 07:21:56.140 Elapsed 89978 usec - Container Temperature (80)
```

Comment: I am working in Windows. Does awk work with windows?

Comment: Yes, but you're far better off installing Cygwin as that gives you a UNIX-like environment from within a window and then you have access to all of the UNIX tools and don't have to deal with Windows' wacky quoting rules, etc.

Comment: what is --label option with grep? Can I use the same for prefixing filename?